# Python pandas Dataframe cleaning from Doubles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can I clean a very huge DataFrame from nearly identical data. I have 4 variables
and always just the last one ist different. For example:

```
 A    B    C    D
13   aaa   AA   200
13   aaa   AA   350
16   aab   CC   150
16   aab   CC   400
22   ddd   RR   1500
22   ddd   RR   700
```

So always D ist different for one pair. How can I delete one, if there is
a big dataframe with 1000 cases?

Thank you

Comment: What's your question? It's not clear. You want to delete one, but based on what? What's the logic for keeping/deleting a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for drop_duplicates:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B', 'C'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```